# OpenGL Depth buffer not applying

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, depth

I am quite new at openGL rendering, and no matter what I do the depth depth won't work.
i obviously already enabled depth test (`glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);`), and i clear the buffer each frame.

But openGL keeps showing last objects rendered in front of others...

You can see my code on my [github](https://github.com/azertyfun/FPS). These are the two files concerned : [Main loop](https://github.com/azertyfun/FPS/blob/master/src/tk/azertyfun/fps/Fps.java). My main loop is at `src/tk/azertyfun/fps/Fps.java` and the render at `src/tk/azertyfun/fps/objects/Mesh.java`.

I am using java and lwjgl.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could create a minimal test case. In any case, the default minimum depth buffer size is 8 bits; perhaps it *is* working but the resolution is too low (effective resolution will depend on the distance between your front and back clip planes as well as how far away from the camera you are [depth buffer values are logarithmic]). Try initializing your `Display` with a `PixelFormat` that requires at least a 12 or 16 bit depth buffer. Does that help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, you correctly enable depth testing before your rendering loop starts with:

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

...and correctly clear the buffer at the beginning of each frame:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

The first thing you then draw in each frame via your render() method is with:

```
skybox.draw();
```

If you look at the implementation of the draw() method in Skybox, you'll see that you have:

```
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

So it is disabled before you actually draw anything and never enabled again.